# how to take id from route.params find it in array from vuex and get title field of this id

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

need help, how to take id from route.params find it in array from vuex and get title field of this id

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the below example answers your question ?

```js
// short
const title = this.$store.state.ALL_CATS.find(element => element.id == this.$route.params.id).title;
// breakdown
const id = this.$route.params.id;
const cats = this.$store.state.ALL_CATS;
const cat = cats.find(element => element.id == id);
const title = cat.title;
```

Comment: where should I put it? sorry im noob

`getTitle() {
        const title = this.$store.state.ALL_CATS.find(element => element.id == this.$route.params.id).title;
      }
`

Comment: It depends, maybe in the created() or updated() lifecycle hook, or in a custom method

Comment: have error: find undefined, i think need to do some getter in vuex

Comment: Ok, let me know if it works or if you have any questions !

Comment: `mounted() {
      const title = this.$store.state.ALL_CATS.find(c => c.id === this.$route.params.id)
    },
`
where should I pass the variable - title? to get result

Comment: You can do something like `window.document.title = title;`